# A knot complexity measure

Tags: knot-theory

Construct a knot/link by fusing two n-tangles together.
([A tangle matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67594/a-tangle-matrix) shows how
this might look for tangles with 6 legs. But lets use 4 legs for a start
as this is far simpler.)
Now, any rational link with 2n crossings can be constructed by fusing
two 4-legged tangles with n crossings (is this obvious?). This is the
lowest complexity in this scheme.
The next more complicated thing would be algebraic links. The Borromei
rings have 6 crossings, but 4+4 is the smallest possible fusion
construction.
The knot 8_18 is AFAIK the smallest "transcendent" example. 
I wasn't able to do better that the obvious 7+1. (Can you find any
m+n-fusion such that max(m,n)<7? I think it should exist. 
There are about 40 tangles with 6 legs, so I didn't try brute force yet :-)
The final stage would be the Borromei double or other counterexamples
to Montesino-Nakanishi. I have reasons to believe that cutting out a
crossing is the best you can do (i.e. 23+1 for the Borromei double).

So I define the complexity to be something like p/q, where q is the
minimum crossing number and p the minimum possible max(m,n). Do you
know any previous work along this scheme (especially those using
a different naming or notation, but are equivalent)?